# MvvmCross: Why are bindings persisting after the view disappears?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

**Note:**

There is a lot of code/diagnostics, first I discuss my problem, followed by a lot of code behind (to help answer any questions), finally I add 3 different blocks of diagnostics to hopefully answer any more questions.  Obviously I don't expect the reader to read through everything.

**The problem:**

Whenever I run my app and display the same view (after dismissing it) my console output displays that previous bindings still exist.

**Details:**

The view I am displaying is as follows:  There is a tableview that has its source bound to my  ViewModel, each of the cells have the left/right labels bound to the ViewModel.

I created the above view as a modal popover view.  Each cell navigates the user to a new view where he/she can edit the field.  Going to the new view and navigating with the 'back' button doesn't cause any problems (to my knowledge).  Once the user presses a button to dismiss the modal popover ("Cancel" for example), the next time the view is displayed, the old bindings seem to exist.  Looking under the **Diagnostics** shows how the values are repeated.  I have no idea why.

I create my tableview and in `GetOrCreateCellFor` I make a new `TimesheetOptionCell` for the cells that I have problems with the bindings.

**Code Behind:**

Inside my `ViewDidLoad()` of my `TimesheetEntryView` I set the `ItemsSource`

```
var source = new TimesheetTableSource (TableView, this);

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<TimesheetEntryView, TimesheetEntryViewModel> ();
set.Bind (source).For (src => src.ItemsSource).To (vm => vm.Options);
set.Apply ();
TableView.Source = source;
```

Inside my `TimesheetTableSource`:

```
ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> _options;
public override System.Collections.IEnumerable ItemsSource 
{
    get 
    {
        return _options;
    }
    set 
    {
        _options = (ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>)value;
        if (_options != null) 
        {
            this.ReloadTableData ();
        }
    }
}

public override int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
{
    return 3;
}

public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
{
    if (section == 0) 
    {
        return _options.Count;
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (section == 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
{
    if(indexPath.Section == 0)
    {
        return TimesheetOptionCell.Create ();
    }

    GenericOneLabelCell cell = GenericOneLabelCell.Create ();

    if (indexPath.Section == 1 && indexPath.Row == 0) 
    {
        cell.LabelText = "Save";
        var set = _timesheetView.CreateBindingSet<TimesheetEntryView, TimesheetEntryViewModel> ();
        set.Bind (cell).For (cll => cll.CellEnabled).To (vm => vm.SaveEnabled);
        set.Apply ();
    } 
    else if (indexPath.Section == 1 && indexPath.Row == 1) 
    {
        cell.LabelText = "Apply";
        var set = _timesheetView.CreateBindingSet<TimesheetEntryView, TimesheetEntryViewModel> ();
        set.Bind (cell).For (cll => cll.CellEnabled).To (vm => vm.SaveEnabled);
        set.Apply ();
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Inside my `TimesheetOptionCell`:

```
    public TimesheetOptionCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        this.DelayBind (() => 
        {
            //set.bind(<label/textView>) implicitly adds .For("Text")
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<TimesheetOptionCell, OptionViewModelBase>();
            set.Bind(FieldDescriptionTextView).To(option => option.OptionValue);
            set.Bind(FieldTitleLabel).To(option => option.Title);
            set.Apply();
        });
    }

    public static TimesheetOptionCell Create ()
    {
        return (TimesheetOptionCell)Nib.Instantiate (null, null) [0];
    }
```

**Diagnostics:**

Here is the first time I display the view:

```
2013-08-06 09:07:13.824 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] mvx: Diagnostic:   6.70 Showing ViewModel TimesheetEntryViewModel
2013-08-06 09:07:13.825 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] TouchNavigation: Diagnostic:   6.70 Navigate requested
2013-08-06 09:07:13.840 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   6.72 Receiving setValue to System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[FCX.Core.ViewModels.ViewModelBase]
2013-08-06 09:07:13.873 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   6.75 Receiving setValue to 7/23/2013
2013-08-06 09:07:13.874 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   6.75 Receiving setValue to Date Worked
2013-08-06 09:07:13.881 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   6.76 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:07:13.882 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   6.76 Receiving setValue to Time Worked
2013-08-06 09:07:13.888 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   6.77 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:07:13.889 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   6.77 Receiving setValue to Company
2013-08-06 09:07:13.894 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   6.77 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:07:13.894 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   6.77 Receiving setValue to Description
2013-08-06 09:07:13.899 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   6.78 Receiving setValue to False
2013-08-06 09:07:13.903 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   6.78 Receiving setValue to False
```

After the second time, I get this:

```
2013-08-06 09:17:43.965 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.85 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:17:43.966 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.85 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:17:43.967 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.85 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:17:43.967 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.85 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:17:43.968 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.85 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:17:43.969 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.85 Receiving setValue to 7/23/2013
2013-08-06 09:17:43.970 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.85 Receiving setValue to 7/23/2013
2013-08-06 09:17:43.971 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.85 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:17:43.972 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.85 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:17:43.972 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] mvx: Diagnostic: 636.85 Showing ViewModel TimesheetEntryViewModel
2013-08-06 09:17:43.973 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] TouchNavigation: Diagnostic: 636.85 Navigate requested
2013-08-06 09:17:44.017 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.90 Receiving setValue to System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[FCX.Core.ViewModels.ViewModelBase]
2013-08-06 09:17:44.024 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.90 Receiving setValue to 7/23/2013
2013-08-06 09:17:44.025 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.90 Receiving setValue to Date Worked
2013-08-06 09:17:44.031 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.91 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:17:44.032 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.91 Receiving setValue to Time Worked
2013-08-06 09:17:44.042 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.92 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:17:44.043 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.92 Receiving setValue to Company
2013-08-06 09:17:44.050 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.93 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:17:44.050 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.93 Receiving setValue to Description
2013-08-06 09:17:44.053 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.93 Receiving setValue to False
2013-08-06 09:17:44.055 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 636.94 Receiving setValue to False
```

After the 10th time:

```
2013-08-06 09:21:08.390 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.27 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.391 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.27 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.391 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.27 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.391 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.27 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.392 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.27 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.392 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.27 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.392 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.27 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.393 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.27 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.393 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.27 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.394 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.27 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.394 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.27 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.395 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.27 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.395 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.396 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.396 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.397 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.397 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.398 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.399 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.399 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.400 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.400 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.400 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.400 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.401 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.401 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.401 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.402 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.402 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.403 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.403 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.404 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.404 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.404 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.404 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.405 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.28 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.406 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.407 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.407 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.408 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.408 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.409 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.409 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.410 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.410 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.411 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.412 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.412 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.413 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.413 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.414 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.414 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.415 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.29 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.415 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.416 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.416 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.417 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.417 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.418 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.418 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.419 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.419 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.420 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.421 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:21:08.421 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:21:08.422 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:21:08.422 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:21:08.423 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:21:08.424 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:21:08.424 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:21:08.425 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.30 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:21:08.425 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.31 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:21:08.426 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.31 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.426 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.31 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.427 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.31 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.427 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.31 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.427 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.31 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.427 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.31 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.428 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.31 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.428 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.31 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.428 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.31 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.428 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] mvx: Diagnostic: 841.31 Showing ViewModel TimesheetEntryViewModel
2013-08-06 09:21:08.429 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] TouchNavigation: Diagnostic: 841.31 Navigate requested
2013-08-06 09:21:08.433 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.31 Receiving setValue to System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[FCX.Core.ViewModels.ViewModelBase]
2013-08-06 09:21:08.440 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.32 Receiving setValue to 7/24/2013
2013-08-06 09:21:08.441 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.32 Receiving setValue to Date Worked
2013-08-06 09:21:08.446 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.33 Receiving setValue to 0:00
2013-08-06 09:21:08.447 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.33 Receiving setValue to Time Worked
2013-08-06 09:21:08.452 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.33 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.453 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.33 Receiving setValue to Company
2013-08-06 09:21:08.459 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.34 Receiving setValue to 
2013-08-06 09:21:08.460 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.34 Receiving setValue to Description
2013-08-06 09:21:08.462 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.34 Receiving setValue to False
2013-08-06 09:21:08.464 FCXiOSv2[16478:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 841.34 Receiving setValue to False
```

Sorry to overwhelm you.  Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand - what does "display the same view (after dismissing it)" mean? You have posted a lot about the internals of the view, but it seems like maybe your question is about the load/appear/disappear of the view and its viewmodel. When you say "the next time the view is displayed" do you mean the same instance?

Comment: I initially create the view through my ViewModel. `ShowViewModel<TimesheetEntryViewModel>`.  Then, my view's `MvxBaseTouchViewPresenter` is overwritten to handle creating a modal popover.
EVERY time the view needs to be displayed in a modal popover, the ViewModel calls the `ShowViewModel`
My custom presenter causes a NEW instance of the view to be created each time.  I NEVER REUSE the old modal popover...that might be my problem?
I assumed each time I dismiss my view (and never reference it again), the bindings would be cleared/deleted.

Comment: To add to that, I already have a different view that works the exact same way at this view's lifecycle (it never reuses the existing view, but makes a new one each time).  I don't have problems with bindings persisting with that view, but it isn't a modal popover.

Comment: Another thought, this is how I get rid of my view: `this.DismissViewController(true, null);`  I don't tell the ViewModel that the view is being dismissed.  Does the viewModel need to handle that navigation?...is it possible the ViewModel does a cleanup on the bindings?

Answer (score 0):

> Why are bindings persisting after the view disappears?

Views can be shown multiple times - they can appear, disappear, appear again, etc - so bindings are normally set up for the lifetime of that view - not just for each appearance.

Each `View` will clear its bindings when it gets disposed. Exactly when the `Dispose` happens is up to iOS and Xamarin.iOS - it depends on when UIKit decides to clear up memory. In the simulator you can often bring this forwards using the Simulate Memory Warning menu option.

If you want the View to clear the bindings at some point earlier then you can call `this.ClearAllBindings()` yourself - but in most cases this isn't necessary as the View and ViewModel normally exist together in a pair for the lifetime of the View.

---

From your description, I'm not sure I entirely follow what you are doing within your custom view presenter nor within your viewmodel location either - I'm not sure what all the `Resolve<> Result` trace lines mean. I suspect that you might be reusing ViewModels and/or Views and that this might be where your multiple-bind is occurring.

Comment: I'm working on the views and I have another person working on the ViewModels.  I wasn't aware that `Resolve<> Result` was his his debugging statements.  I removed that from the diagnostics output, to avoid confusion.
Also, our current setup instantiates all the ViewModels at the beginning of runtime as singletons, to allow our views to `Resolve<>` them.  Based off what you've told us, and some other issues we are having, we're going to try to refactor our setup to pair the views/ViewModels back together.  (rather than have the ViewModel's lifecycle well exceed the view's)